How to only suppress warning outputs from cryptsetup?
In Linux in Bash i run a script with some cryptsetup calls like
--luks2-metadata-size=16k  --luks2-keyslots-size=256k .... luksFormat .... 
that brings Warning outputs.
I know and understand, but i will these Warnings not see at the screen.
How can i suppress them, but show error messages?

can you give me please an example?
